# Smile Elasticsuite error after upgrade to magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, elastic

I have upgraded my site from 2.2.6 to 2.3.2.
After upgrade when i access admin panel i am getting error
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::elasticsuite_menu)

I removed elasticsuite and installed again by following command.
composer require smile/elasticsuite 2.8.4

But the issue still persists.
Can anyone help me plz.

Comment: Can you please add a menu.xml file(module-elasticsuite-core/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml)?

Comment: what should be inside that?

Comment: <add id="Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::elasticsuite_menu" title="ElasticSuite" translate="title" module="Smile_ElasticsuiteCore" sortOrder="50" resource="Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::menu"/> this code present in menu.xml file ?

Comment: yes this code is present in menu.xml file

Answer (score 0):

*Upgrading to Magento 2.3.2 can cause compatibility issues with third-party extensions, such as Smile ElasticSuite. Here are some general troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue:

Check for compatibility: Verify that the version of Smile ElasticSuite you are using is compatible with Magento 2.3.2. If it's not, you may need to upgrade to a newer version of the extension or revert to an earlier version of Magento.

Clear cache: Clear your Magento cache by running the following command from the Magento root directory:

```
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
```

*This can resolve conflicts between new code and old cached code.

Check the logs: Check the Magento error logs in var/log/ to see if there are any specific error messages related to Smile ElasticSuite. This can give you more information about the root cause of the issue.

Reinstall the extension: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Smile ElasticSuite to ensure that all files are installed correctly and that the extension is properly configured.

Contact Smile ElasticSuite support: If none of the above steps resolve the issue, reach out to Smile ElasticSuite support for further assistance. They may be able to provide more specific troubleshooting steps or insights into the issue.*